# How can i parse this value from string into Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parsing

```
let x = "[{\"{\\\"value\\\":\\\"+2333333333\\\",\\\"phone_number_type\\\":null}\"}]"
let parseX=JSON.parse(x)
console.log(x)
```

//I want the output to [{"value":"2333333333","phone_number_type":null}]

Comment: What is generating that string? There's excessive escaping in there...

Comment: Also why do you expect output Array if your JSON start with `{`?

Comment: I am getting this string from an API as it is and wanted to convert this string into an Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  //I have resolved this problem so what we can do is : 
 
x='[{"\\"value\\":\\"aliwasiq41@gmail.com\\",\\"email_address_type\\":null}"}]';
x=x.replaceAll('\\', '');
x=x.replace('{"',"")
x=x.replace('"}',"")
console.log(JSON.parse(str));  

//In this way you can parse the value to 
 [{"value":"2333333333","phone_number_type":null}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect JSON.parse to throw an error because the JSON string in x is invalid JSON. See [JSON.org](https://json.org) for more details. The [{{...}}] is invalid it should be [{...}]